# launch .launch from another launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how to open a launch file from another launch file in ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42814/launch-.launch-from-another-launch-file/) by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on 2012-09-02**:
please can anyone help me out in this
http://answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/http%3A//answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
<include file="$(find package_name)/directory/another.launch"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 20

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karan4515](https://answers.ros.org/users/3123/karan4515/) on 2012-09-02**:
please can anyone help me out in this http://answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/http%3A//answers.ros.org/question/42849/how-to-launch-a-launch-file-from-python-code/

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-02**:
Please do not post links to your own questions in other questions because that might cause emails people just don't want. Instead, please tag your questions correctly to make sure the right people are notified.

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2014-05-06**:
If some my commands are rosrun, then how to automate these commands inside launch files??

**Comment by [TFabbri](https://answers.ros.org/users/74847/tfabbri/) on 2021-05-20**:
Is there a way to specify in the `<include ...>` to `--wait` the ROSCore as in the `roslaunch` command?